# Reading a text file with numbers in R

Tags: r

I am sorry if I am asking a repeat question but I am unable to understand with previous posts.
I have a text file names bins.txt which has the following data in the form of numbers.

```
5
6
46
54
```

I want to access the file and work on these numbers. Also please mention both the way I can access the numbers randomly like the number at 3rd line which is 46 or second line which is 6. etc

Comment: Have a look at read.table(). For specific rows look at skip and nrows options of the same command.

Comment: Is there any documentation where I can find it?

Comment: type `?read.table` into the console. This will launch the help file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Load data

```
data <- read.csv("bins.txt", header = FALSE)
```

## Read 3rd line

```
data[3, ]
```

## Read nth line

```
data[n, ]
```

Comment: Is data a list/array in this one? I have to use the values of data one by one and perform some function on them

Comment: data is a data.frame. Say your column name is "a" which you can check with `names(data)`. To access say 3rd value in column "a", use `data$a[3]`